# how to run node.js on browser via linux apache server?

Tags: linux, node.js, apache

I installed `node.js` on `linux server`. I'm able to run `node.js` on command line, but not able to run on browser.

Did I clearly explained what I want?

I have a domain `ram.com` that point to particular location on my server `/var/www/html/ram.com/`.

I created `node.js` pages on this location `/var/www/html/ram.com` .How can I access this page on browser?

My `apache` running on `80` port. Can you explain any changes in `apache` configuration?

I'm new to `node.js` can you explain clearly.

Answer (score 1):

To use `Node.js` to serve your website, you just need to type `node yourFileName.js` in command line to start the server.

I don't really know how your pages look like. You need `*.js` files as `Node.js` source files, and `Node.js` work as backend. If you mean `*.html`, you can access them when the server program is running.

Actually, `Node.js` has its own built-in web server, just like `PHP` + `Apach`e. So you don't need to use Apache, and I don't think `Node.js` and `apache` can work together without other tools.

This is my first answer in Stack Overflow, hope that can help you.

Comment: Your welcome. Always try to format your Q&A they way others can easily read them.